# Powershell loop back to section

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I tried looking for a solution for this for weeks but still not finding the right solution so I am hoping I can get someone to point me to the right area.
I have a powershell script for adding new users to mutiple teams group based of the selection the script runner selects but it only allows me to select one group at a time then I need to run the script again. What I want to do is after the user selects the group they need to add the user too, then be prompted a yes or no question on if the user needs to be added to another group. Here is what I got

```
Import-Module MicrosoftTeams
Connect-MicrosoftTeams
#enter the users email address
$user = Read-Host "What is the user's email address?"
#Chose what groups the user needs to be added to
Write-Host “Which teams group do you want to add the $user to?
  1 Resources           2  Sales
  3  Clients”
  
      $Team = Read-Host “Enter the  Teams #”
      Switch ($Team){
          1 {$Team = Add-TeamUser -GroupId xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx -User $user -Role member}
          2 {$Team = Add-TeamUser -GroupId xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx -User $user -Role member}
          3 {$Team = Add-TeamUser -GroupId xxxx-xxxx-xxxx -User $user -Role member}
      }
      #Prompt for more groups or exit
          $Resources = "Do you need to add the user to another group? [Y/N]"
          do {
              $response = Read-Host -Prompt $Resources
              if ($response -eq 'y') { Start over from Write-host
                  
              }
          } until ($response -eq 'n') 
          write-host "$user will not be added to anymore groups." 
          exit
```

As you can see at the bottom is where I have the issue of looping back to the section I want to restart at, but really unsure about getting that to work. Any suggestions would be amazing.
Thank you

Comment: Wrap your initial choices into a function then then they press Y to select another group you just call the function

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion as I never made a function before. I tried it out and that works perfectly. Thank you again.